# How do you access an outlet in a collectionitem?

Tags: cocoa, save, nsarraycontroller, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem

I have an NSCollectionView which is populated by collection items. An array controller is used to add the items to the view. Each item has two outlets, an imageview and textview (not field), that the user can edit themselves. How would you gain access to the outlets in each collection item so I can save the contents of each item to a plist file?